# How to check if form field is empty using PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to check if the field is empty. If it is, redirect to sign uppage. Right now, it just keeps on creating multiple account with NULL username and password. I tried using strlen(), but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php
        try{
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $hash = crypt($password_signup, '$3a$08$2'); // salt 

        $connection = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tongue', 'web', 'lapming1');
        $connection -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connection -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        require_once("functions.php");

        $sql = 'SELECT email, hash FROM user WHERE email=:username';
        $row = login ($sql, $connection, $username_signup);

        if ($username = false){
            header("Location: sign_up.php?error");
        };

        if ($row) {
            header("Location: sign_up.php?msg=1");
        }
        else {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO user(email, hash) VALUES (:username, :password)';
            create($sql, $connection, $username_signup, $password_signup);
            header("Location: index.php");
        };


    $connection = null;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can any one tell me why this guy got a -1 ??? If he knows the answer he would not be asking .. am sure some of us once had similar issues in the past .....

Comment: @Baba, thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the error .. you are using basic assignment operator "=" insted of Comparison operators "=="

Change

```
   if ($username = false){
        header("Location: sign_up.php?error");
    };
```

To

```
   if ($username == false){
        header("Location: sign_up.php?error");
    };
```

Or Better Approach

```
  if (empty($username){
        header("Location: sign_up.php?error");
    };
```

Thanks
:)

Comment: You missed a parenthesis ending on the last one.

Answer (score 2):

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
if(!empty($username)) {
   ....is not empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easier this way

```
if (!strlen($username)){
 header("Location: sign_up.php?error");
};
```

And you are not using correct comparison operators

`$username = false` assigns the boolean value `false` to `$username` and will always be returned as true, and thus the header will keep on being sent.